# django rest - create object with less fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework in a project. I set all the Group model attributes in serializer fields, so when I make a GET request, I receive all data. Ok. But this became a trouble when some user want create a group (POST method), once I get the user ID in request - what generate a bad request.

My model:

```
class Group(models.Model):

    class Meta:
         app_label = 'base'

    PRIVACY = Choices(
        ('0', u'Público'),
        ('1', 'Particular'),
        ('2', 'Secreto'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=62, unique=False)
    privacy = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRIVACY)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='admin')
    member = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')
```

My serializer:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # admin = serializers.CharField(source='admin.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'privacy', 'status', 'end_date', 'date_created', 'admin')
```

My view:

```
class GroupList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
               mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               generics.GenericAPIView):

    """
    List all groups, or create a new group.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(admin=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

A update request exemple:

```
var data = {
    'name': 'New name',
    'privacy': '0',
    'end_date':'2015-12-22 19:53:42',
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/groups/',
    method: 'POST',
    data:data
}).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

The error:

```
{"admin":["This field is required."]}
```

Comment: You need to set `null=True` for admin field in your model.

Comment: there is no `admin_id`  variable in your data object.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to set the admin field as [`read_only`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments).